# getting nth:child jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html block

```
    <div id="pane" class="MosadBoxRight scroll_pane" style="overflow: hidden; height: 590px; width: 250px; padding: 0px 41px 0px 0px;">
                <div class="MosadBoxRightKoteretpopUp">text</div>
                <div class="area" id="area1">
<a iframe="/4746929" style="cursor:pointer" class="alink" id="aLink">example1
 </a></div>
                <div class="area" id="area2">
<a  iframe="4746929" style="cursor:pointer" class="alink" id="aLink">example1 
</a></div>
                <div class="area" id="area3">
<a  iframe="/474692946" style="cursor:pointer" class="alink" id="aLink">example1
</a></div>

        </div>
```

I have also this javascript function

```
  function nextchapter() {
     loc=loc+1;
     var contextCmsPage = $("#pane .alink:nth-child(0)").attr("iframe");


     }
```

and a button that call this function

```
<input type="button" id="btnc" onclick="nextchapter()" value="check" />
```

I am trying to get nth child of class `alink` in father Div `pane`

I getting undefinded for  `$("#pane .alink:nth-child(0)").attr("iframe");`

I also tried

```
$("#pane").find(".alink:nth-child(0)").attr("iframe");
```

with same result

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Baaroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the nth child but the nth element of class `alink`.

Use this :

```
var link = $("#pane .alink").eq(0);
```

Comment: work like charm ,can you please explain in short what are the differences between $("#pane .alink").eq(0) and $("#pane").find(".alink:nth-child(0)")?

Comment: nth-child counts regarding the immediate parent of the element (here the link), while eq counts the elements inside their collection.